# Implementation of Interface inherited of another Interfaces

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have an abstract interface IA, which is inherited from interfaces IB and IC with different behaviours. Also I have implementations of this interfaces B from IB and C from IC. What if I need class A implementing IA, but part of implementation it has in B and C. How to provide this.

**EDITED:**
Minimal, complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

class IB
{
public:
    virtual void function_B() = 0;
};

class IC
{
public:
    virtual void function_C() = 0;
};

class IA : public IB, public IC
{
};


class B : public IB
{
public:
    virtual void function_B()
    {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

class C : public IC
{
public:
    virtual void function_C()
    {
        std::cout << "C\n";
    }
};

// then I want IA implementation, but also to use
// ready implementation B and C

// this way doesn't work, the class A stays abstract
class A: public IA, public B, public C
{

};


int main()
{
    IA *a = new A;
    a->function_B();
    a->function_C();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did your attempt work or not work? Could you please create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us?

Comment: Should `A` inherit `B` and/or `C`? That is, does it make sense to say "every object which is an `A` is also a `B`"? (Note this decision does not involve the fact that the classes want to share some of the code implementing their behaviors.)

Comment: Yes, exactly. A should inherit both B and C. It's better to say: every object IB is a part of object IA (by behaviour).

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question was kind of unclear to me. Could you please provide a concrete example of what you want?

Comment: I added code to the question.

Comment: Ah yes. You need to repeat every function from `IA` inside the `A`, even if all they do is to redirect to `B` or `C`. Also, it's a good idea to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: You need to use [virtual inheritance](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) to solve the `diamond problem`

Comment: @Arkadiy  Ok. Thank you - it works. But, by the way, have to do some more works.

Comment: @VictorGubin No, I think, there is no diamond problems, classes IB and IC have no common ancestor.

Comment: @Alex Look what you have ... class IA : public `IB`, public IC ... ...  ... class B : public `IB`  ... class A: public `IA`, public `B`, public C ...  So this is actually `diamond problem`.  Draw   you inheritance on the paper, and you will see the `diamond`. But if you add `B: public virtual IB` and `IA: public virtual IB` it will solve this.

Comment: @VictorGubin Ah, exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `A` inherits two times from `IB`, once via `IA` and once via `B`. The same is true for `IC` as well.

To solve this [diamon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) you have to use virtual inheritance wherever a class inherits *directly* from `IC` or `IB`:

```
class IA : public virtual IB, public virtual IC
{
};


class B : public virtual IB
{
public:
    virtual void function_B()
    {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

class C : public virtual IC
{
public:
    virtual void function_C()
    {
        std::cout << "C\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-implement every function of `IA` in `A`. But those can be simple forwarders.

I would also recomend aggregation over inheritance, if possible, i.e. not inherit from `B` and `C`, but make them members:

```
class A : public IA {
    B b_;
    C c_;
public:
    void function_B() override { b_.b(); }
    void function_C() override { c_.c(); }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It will be an alternative for  **Arkadiy**'s advice . "to repeat every function from IA inside the A, even if all they do is to redirect to B or C"

Answer (score 0):

In your code `class A` is inherited from `class IA` , `class B` and `class C` and `class IA` is a abstract class so you can't instantiate it.

And due to `Class IA` is abstract so you`class A` also become abstract.
So you need to override the virtual function of `class IA` (i-e functions of `class IB` and `class IC`) in `class A`.

So you need to reimplement the above functions in `class A`

```
class A : public IA,public B,public C {
public:
    void function_B() override { std::cout << "B\n";}
    void function_C() override { std::cout << "C\n";}
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly wrote the comment below your answer. It doesn't solve the problem, cause I already have overriding of class IA in classes IB and IC, and want to A use them.

Comment: Why is there problem with my answer ??

Comment: watch above comment

Comment: But you are doing a mistake and i mentioned your mistake to you .

Comment: @AlexNevskiy by the way best of luck . Happy coding

Comment: It wasn't a mistake, I knew that A need to implement Interfaces's pure methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187666/discussion-between-hamza-s-and-alex-nevskiy).